# inapp purchases re-acquire

Tags: iphone, ipad, in-app-purchase

Is there a way to re-acquire the inapp purchases a customer has already made if he re-installs the app on a new iphone? Thus saving the need for the customer to go through the purchase procedure again, to be told he has already purchased it?

Thanks

Fitto

Comment: Only if you keep the users purchase history on your server, and automatically check your records. But even then your user would still have to redownload the IAPs.

Comment: search stackoverflow for "restore purchase". that's the correct term

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the `SKPaymentQueue` class and the method `restoreCompletedTransactions`